# Translate transformation WPF - ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, transform, render

I have a ListBox with few items in it. I need to apply translate transform to one of the item, so that other items should arrange respectively. Say if I set Y="100" to second item, then other items under 2 nd item (except 1st) should move down 100 pixels.

I though Layout transform will do this (instead of render trnasform). But seems Translation wont work for Layout transform.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx

Any other approach is really appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Can't you just set the item's `Margin` appropriately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to translate items in a ListBox, you may set the `Margin` property of their container in an `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding ItemMargin}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemText}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Setting the `Margin` of the item container instead of that of the item (e.g. the TextBlock in the DataTemplate) prevents that the selection rectangle covers the margin area.

Adding items like shown below creates a gap of 100 pixels between the first and second item.

```
var items = new List<object>();
items.Add(new { ItemText = "Item 1", ItemMargin = new Thickness() });
items.Add(new { ItemText = "Item 2", ItemMargin = new Thickness(0, 100, 0, 0) });
items.Add(new { ItemText = "Item 3", ItemMargin = new Thickness() });
DataContext = items;
```